# File upload in React Native through fetch, XHR and axios fails on Android but works on iOS

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I have looked at every possible solution to this on stack overflow, Github issues, gists and what not. None of them have worked.

Basically I am trying to upload an image captured through react-native-camera onto a Java API and it works on iOS both on the simulator and on a physical device.

```
function handleOnPictureTaken (image) {
  const imageName = image.uri.split('/').pop()
  const imageExtension = imageName.split('.').pop()
  const imageType = `image/${imageExtension}`
  const source = { uri: image.uri, type: imageType, name: imageName }
  onPhotoSelected(source)
}

function onPhotoSelected (image) {    
  const photoData = new FormData()
  image = {
    ...image,
    uri: image.uri.replace('file://', '')
  }
  photoData.append('file', image)
  uploadFile(photoData)
}

function uploadFile(image) {
  const config = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    credentials: 'include'
  }
  if (method === 'POST' || method === 'PUT') {
    if (config.headers['Content-Type'] === 'application/json') {
      config.body = JSON.stringify(data)
    } else {
      config.body = data
    }
  }

  return fetch(url, config).then(checkJSON)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(parseJSON)
    .catch(rejectRequest)
}
```

This works perfectly on iOS. But on Android, I keep getting `Network request failed` as shown below

```
Stack trace: TypeError: Network request failed
at anonymous (http://192.168.0.103:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:28469:31)
at call (native)
at dispatchEvent (http://192.168.0.103:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:34597:31)
at setReadyState (http://192.168.0.103:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:33681:33)
at __didCompleteResponse (http://192.168.0.103:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:33508:29)
at apply (native)
at anonymous (http://192.168.0.103:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:33618:52)
at apply (native)
at emit (http://192.168.0.103:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:6202:42)
at apply (native)
at __callFunction (http://192.168.0.103:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5626:49)
at anonymous (http://192.168.0.103:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5348:31)
at __guard (http://192.168.0.103:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5580:15)
at callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://192.168.0.103:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5347:21)
```

I have been struggling to get this work. The physical Android device is on the same WiFi. Normal POST requests are working. But only uploading files are failing.

If anyone has any suggestions, do let me know.

Comment: did you allow http traffic in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: check if android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" presents in your manifest

Comment: I just added that line. Re run ```npm run android``` on to my device. But still no help.

Comment: But usesCleartextTraffic is for allowing ```http``` requests and ```https``` requests are allowed by default. And I am making a call using ```https```.

Comment: can you check the logcat in Android Studio?

Comment: I found this in logcat
```E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"```
```E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.hal1.packagelist"```
```D/Camera: app passed NULL surface```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do check inside the AndroidManifest.xml for the main file,

```
 <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Does it include this text  `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

And just reember to make a new apk, and then check on that,

UPDAT:

Whoever is still struggling with this issue. it's happening because of Flipper network plugin.
I disabled it and things work just fine.

My workaround to make this work is commenting out line number 43

```
38      NetworkFlipperPlugin networkFlipperPlugin = new NetworkFlipperPlugin();
39      NetworkingModule.setCustomClientBuilder(
40          new NetworkingModule.CustomClientBuilder() {
41            @Override
42            public void apply(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
43      //        builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
44            }
45          });
46      client.addPlugin(networkFlipperPlugin);
```

in this file `android/app/src/debug/java/com/maxyride/app/drivers/ReactNativeFlipper.java`

First make a cleanbuild,
1.Bundle your app
2.CLea folder by cd android and then ./gradlew clean
3.Make debug apk by ./gradlew assembleDebug

Justcheck Github, found this, please check.

**UPDATE2:**

LINK [link-rn](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551#issuecomment-611085378)

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: I haven't made a new APK but I ran ```npm run android``` which created a releaseDebug and installed it on my device. It still gives me the same error.

Comment: very strange, but wait a seond, did you check how file is fetched on android devices, is it in ormat of 'file://', '' or somethingelse., coz i remember something vaguely, both gives the output in diff format. do chek that once, maybe coz the image isnt replaced properly in the formadata , hence te error

Comment: Yes its in the format of ```"file:///data/user/0/***/cache/Camera/0535c7af-040d-4a1a-b255-0d4008b313b9.jpg"```

Comment: @shatyajeet please check updated answer, found an issue on github, and please,make a new clean build on android , rather than npm run android and check once. hope it helps

Comment: please add the link to the Github issue which you found. Thanks.

Comment: @shatyajeet do chck the updated answer, have listed the link there, do upvote and mark as accepted if it helped you

Comment: Glad it helped. You can appreciate it by upvoting too. Would be of great help.